# Visual Studio Solution Dependencies

Tags: c++, visual-studio, external-dependencies

I'm working at an organization with a product suite based on several hundred Visual Studio solutions (mostly C++). Some of these solutions generate libraries that are used by other solutions and there's also a common "include" folder containing headers that shared by multiple modules.

The issue is that the dependencies are not explicitly stated anywhere, and the build system resolves dependencies by specifying a linear build order that makes sure the dependent modules get built at the right time. This works well for the build system but leaves developers at a disadvantage when trying to work on components with many direct and indirect external dependencies. For example, I might want to edit one of the library projects or shared headers and then build all the affected modules without necessarily knowing ahead of time which ones are affected. Another use case involves building a module after doing a fresh pull from TFS and having the modules it depends on built first without having to build the entire system.

I am wondering if there is/are any tool(s) available that can automate dependency generation for building large projects. I have considered creating a few really big solutions that encapsulate the other solutions but that seems really awkward and clumsy. Also, I don't like the idea of having developers manually specify dependencies as it can error prone, especially with such a large code base. I worked with scons a few years ago and really liked the way it could parse source files and automatically discover all the dependencies dependencies. Is there anything available today that can do the same thing with Visual Studio solutions?

This is not a duplicate of [Visual Studio: how to handle project dependencies right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081002/visual-studio-how-to-handle-project-dependencies-right)

I need to emphasize the magnitude of the problem I am trying to solve. This is a very large existing code base. In the main directory there are several hundred sub-folders, each one containing one of more VS solutions (not projects). Each solution, in turn, contains one or more projects. As I said before, I'm not trying to establish dependencies among a few projects in a solution. The problem is much bigger than that. I'm trying to find a way to establish dependencies among the solutions themselves (several hundred of them). For example, one solution may contain some projects that generate libraries for security, others for communications, etc. There may be, for example, dozens of solutions that use the communications libraries. So essentially I'm trying to create a directed a cyclic graph with hundreds of nodes and potentially tens of thousands of edges.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio: how to handle project dependencies right?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081002/visual-studio-how-to-handle-project-dependencies-right)

Comment: Use CMake... :)

Comment: Is CMake able to scan a large number of existing VS solutions and generate dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

You could use cmake (https://cmake.org/). With it, you can specify several libraries and apps to be built. Once configured, you can modify a project and the build will just update the dependent projects. Cmake also provides a visual studio generator, so that you can continue using that IDE.

A possible disavantage to you is that, to configure, you must explictly specify, for each project (library or executable), with what projects it must be linked and what folders it must include. There are ways to define some global includes and links, but the use will depends on your problem.

Comment: That's ALMOST what I'm looking for except that I want to automate, to the highest degree possible, the discovery of dependencies among many solutions. This as a very large codebase containing millions of lines of code. Manually configuring dependencies in this situation would be to costly and error prone.

Answer (score 0):

VS does track dependencies (by parsing source files). It doesn't make sense that something could automatically set dependencies of your VS projects, in any other build tools you'd still have to specify in some way that for linking project `A.exe` you need to use `B.lib`.

If you use newer VS versions you should simply add references to lib to your exe/dll projects. If you manually added project dependencies, most likely you should remove them all, especially make sure you don't make static lib projects dependent on each other. VS allows you to do that (for example, if build of one library generates some source files that another static lib uses), but in general these shouldn't have any dependencies and this allows VS to optimize builds by building them in parallel.

For example, commonly you could have some kind of Base.lib, then System.lib and Graphics.lib. All of these are user by your App.exe. System.lib uses code from Base.lib, Graphics.lib uses code from System.lib and Base.lib. So, naturally the dependency chain is clear and you go and set them in VS, and that's a mistake! In cases like this in VS you should make these 4 libs independent and only App.exe should be dependent on all these libs (e.g. it should have references to all of these). VS will figure out what is the the correct dependency of these projects.

Regarding Cmake case: it simply generates VS projects and solutions, if you use VS then cmake cannot do more than VS itself can.